# como obtener el color de enfasis de windows 10 usando vb.net

Tags: vb.net, windows

```
 namespace Garantias_CL
{
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public object Resources { get; private set; }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            BackColor = new SolidColorBrush((Color)Resources["SystemAccentColor"]);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: intento realizar esto bien sea en c# o vb.net

Comment: Puedes probar con `(Color)Application.Current.Resources["SystemAccentColor"];`